# When using an second monitor, is it possible to move the cursor off both sides of the screen?

Tags: macos, display, mouse

For example, I have a MBP connected to an external monitor. I use both screens but hate the fact that I have to go all the way to the left side of the external monitor (which is huge) in order to go back to my primary screen. Say that I'm on my primary screen and I move my cursor off the left side of the screen, I'd like my cursor to appear on the right side of my external monitor. Also, if I moved my mouse off the right side of my primary screen I'd like my cursor to appear on the left side of my external screen. I'm sure that functionality isn't built into OSX, but are there third party products that do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, sure. Use Wraparound (I haven't tried it, but it should do what you're asking). Download it here: http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/19599/wraparound.

Comment: Is there a way to also just directly send the mouse to the alternate screen via a keyboard shortcut? If i'm exactly in the middle of a really huge screen, I find that hitting a kb shortcut would be easier than scrolling even half of the large screen. :)

Comment: @KaushikGopal Yes there is: CatchMouse http://ftnew.com/catchmouse.html

Comment: "This app is no longer supported by it's developer." ; are there any relevant solutions to this for recent macOS (Monterey, etc.)?

Answer (score 4):

Wraparound does exactly what you are looking for, but it's worth noting for later readers what OS X will do without additional software:

> Say that I'm on my primary screen and I move my cursor off the left
>   side of the screen, I'd like my cursor to appear on the right side of
>   my external monitor.

This part you can do without adding Wraparound.  Go to:

```
System Preferences > Displays > Arrangement
```

"Arrangement" only displays when the second monitor is connected.  If "Mirror Displays" is unchecked, you will see two or more blue boxes.  The white horizontal bar at the top of one box represents the OS X menu bar, which is usually on your primary display (although you can move it to another display by dragging it there).

By clicking and dragging the boxes you can reposition the boxes relative to each other.  This lets you place the secondary display is to the left of the primary display, or along any edge other of that display.

This also allows you to position the secondary display higher or lower along each edge of the primary display, leaving corners open on the primary display for any Active Screen Corners that you have enabled in the Expose settings.

Comment: Doesn't answer my question, but I'll upvote you anyway because it's good information.

Comment: Many thanks.  I had the same problem, or a similar one at any rate, and preferred a keyboard shortcut to screen wrapping.  So if you want another answer that does not answer your question, that would be CatchMouse.app (http://ftnew.com/catchmouse.html) :)  Now if only I could figure out how to get that answer to Kaushik Gopal above (not enough rep to comment on gtmtg's answer).